# Android Studio says "Expression expected"

Tags: expected-exception

Android Studio tells there is an error in Java file, in string             `summonButton2();` Android Studio says "Expression expected".

I want the method `summonButton2` to be launched automatically. I undesrtand that I'm doing it wrong. What exactly and is there any other way to start a method, except adding it to `onCreate` method? Thanks in advance.

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    int numberOfLinesLeft = 3;

    Button secondaryActivityAddButton;

    LinearLayout llForSecondaryButton;

    LinearLayout llForSecondaryEditText;

    EditText et;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        summonButton2();
    }

        public void summonButton2(View view){

            llForSecondaryButton = findViewById(R.id.secondaryButton);
            secondaryActivityAddButton = new Button(this);

            secondaryActivityAddButton.setText("" + numberOfLinesLeft);
            llForSecondaryButton.addView(secondaryActivityAddButton);

            secondaryActivityAddButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View view) {

                    plusTextField();

                    if(numberOfLinesLeft == 0) {
                        view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }

                }
            });

        }

    public void plusTextField() {

        llForSecondaryEditText = findViewById(R.id.linearLayout1);

        // add edittext
        et = new EditText(this);
        et.setText("text" + numberOfLinesLeft       );
        llForSecondaryEditText.addView(et);
        numberOfLinesLeft--;
        secondaryActivityAddButton.setText("" + numberOfLinesLeft);

    }
}
```

Comment: The method's signature indicates it expects a View object to be sent when called.

Comment: summonButton2(View);  - all the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
summonButton2(new View(this));
```

Helped in my case.